# Spring Core Framework : Exception in thread NoClassDefFoundError for ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I have created a simple program which uses Spring Core framework and am trying to build it using gradle. am able to compile project successfully but when i try to execute program using

> java -jar build\libs\knightFramework-0.1.0.jar

then am facing bellow runtime exception but same program is working fine in Eclipse.
Please Suggest changes i have to make in build.gradle.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Code structure 
src\main\java\knightFramework -> Contains classes BraveKnight.java, KnightConfig.java, KnightMain.java,  SlayDragonQuest.java and Interfaces: Knight.java, Quest.java

KnightMain.java

O/P of bk.embarkOnQuest()-> is just sysout("Embarking on Slay Dragon Quest")

```
package knightFramework;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class KnightMain{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(knightFramework.KnightConfig.class);

        Knight bk = (Knight) ac.getBean("braveKnightBean");
        bk.embarkOnQuest();

    }
}
```

KnightConfig.java

```
package knightFramework;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KnightConfig {

    @Bean
    public Knight braveKnightBean(){
        return new BraveKnight(slayDragonQuest());
    }

    @Bean
    public Quest slayDragonQuest(){
        return new SlayDragonQuest();
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'knightFramework.KnightMain'

jar {
    baseName = 'knightFramework'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'knightFramework.KnightMain'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE")
}
```

Comment: Try removing the manifest configuration in the jar task. That is done automatically by the application plugin. Check the generated manifest.

Comment: @JB Nizet i tried that one am getting this exception no main manifest attribute, in build\libs\

and also if i use buld.gradle file from https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ it runs perfectly the only change present is related to apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

Comment: @JB Nizet does spring-boot plugin plays any role in execution of jar

Comment: If you are creating a jar you will need to specify which jars it needs when you do `java -jar Your.jar` you should use `java -cp all.jars.here -jar Your.jar` to add those jars to the class path. The guide you are referencing to is using Spring Boot which creates a runnable jar, however the normal jar proces doesn't do that.

Comment: @M.Deinum am new to spring framework and generating jars with gradle but I think gradle should able to build jars which will not need to provide additional attributes like here adding external jar to classpath so please suggest changes in terms of build.gradle

Comment: @JBNizet does spring-boot plugin plays any role in execution of jar

Comment: I've never used spring-boot. But I'd expect the official instructions to be correct: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/. No need for the application plugin if you use the spring-boot plugin.